# Scheduled Task no longer running: Exception code: 0xe0434352

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I had a scheduled task that has ran successfully for over two months. On March 12th/13th the task stopped running and I started to receive the following error each time it tried to run each day following the March 12th/13th date.

What confuses me the most is that it successfully ran over two months and then stopped working. I checked with my networking team and they nor I can think of any changes occurred that would affect this.

When I manually execute the program with the same execution path stored in the Task Scheduler it runs successfully.

Any advice is appreciated and troubleshooting suggestions are encouraged.

```
Faulting application name: CreateAndUploadDataV2.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56faea31
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.19160, time stamp: 0x56bcd73c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000965d
Faulting process id: 0x10d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18a6aeee70906
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Administrator.COMPANYNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GNGACN1V.EY9\9HMZ7BQN.Q3P\crea..tion_456a55e2c103c34b_0001.0000_2d85cccaa67bcee3\CreateAndUploadDataV2.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 330cd66f-f65e-11e5-8535-000c298b7f97
```

Here is the .NET Runtime Error:

```
Application: CreateAndUploadDataV2.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding, Int32, Boolean)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding, Int32)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String)
   at CreateAndUploadDataV2.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I suspect whatever error there is, it will be related to the task itself.
Have you tried executing it manually? Are there any logs?

Comment: @rvs I have ran it manually and it works manually. I'll update the post with that fact. Regarding the logs, which logs would you like to see?